# Unable to access https site from my Windows XP IE 8

Tags: windows-xp

I'm unable to access the following website from my Internet Explorer 8 under Windows XP with `Internet Explorer unable to display web page` error. By the other hand the FireFox browser at the same Windows XP can access this website.

How to solve the issue with IE8 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The site in question uses a [modern security configuration](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) that doesn't support any of the [cipher suites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite) present in Internet Explorer 8 (or IE <= 10, or Android <= 4.3, for that matter).

You can see that the SSL handshake fails in older browsers in this handshake simulation on SSL Labs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.mycommerce.com

Google over HTTPS still allows for IE 8, but doesn't allow for IE 6. Some sites such as GitHub.com [don't support IE on Windows XP at all](https://github.com/blog/1937-improving-github-s-ssl-setup) due to outdated cipher suites.

This is a server-side configuration that is not within your control. You can either upgrade to IE 11 or use Firefox (although [Firefox 52 is the last version to support Windows XP](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Important-Firefox-is-ending-support-for-Windows-XP-and-Vista/ta-p/31270)).

Comment: Note that the key component here is not IE 8, but Windows XP - *any* IE-based browser running on that OS will use an out-dated SSL/TLS implementation provided by the OS. So even if IE 11 was available for that OS, it wouldn't solve the issue. Firefox and Chrome do not rely on the OS-provided implementation, so do not have this problem. However, they no longer release updates for Windows XP either, so eventually they too will become too old to render some sites.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IE8
2. Click on the `Tools` menu
3. Go to `Internet option`
4. Then `Advanced` tab
5. Check if both `SSL2.0` and `SSL3.0` are checked

Comment: SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0 are already checked

Comment: @alexanoid hmm, is the time on that computer correct?

Comment: yes, the time is also correct

Comment: @alexanoid Can you send us a screenshot of what you get once you try to access a secure website?

Comment: Something similar to this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgCVK.png

Comment: @alexanoid What is the difference between that screenshot and what you are facing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56060/discussion-between-rany-and-alexanoid).