# Able to get online with Windows XP VM (Internet Explorer), but unable to access websites (UTM, MacOS)

Tags: macos, windows-xp, virtual-machine, internet-explorer

I've recently installed Windows XP through UTM on MacOS Ventura. It was all going smoothly until I ran into errors opening up any other website than Google on Internet Explorer. I'm trying to install another browser, but to do that I need to have PHP installed - which I'm unable to install, as I reach the "page cannot be displayed" link for every option I try. What are the workarounds for this?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1192520/unable-to-access-https-site-from-my-windows-xp-ie-8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a good Virtual Machine App.

I have XP running here.  Host machine is Windows 11 Pro.  XP Pro is a Guest Machine using VMware Workstation.  You can use VMware Fusion on a Mac.

Internet Explorer has died.  So I install Google Chrome and it works.

Remember that XP is dead, little works on it. Chrome works, but not every site. Security is non-existent.

However, to your specific question:  Inside XP, Internet works and Google Chrome (old version) works also.   New York Times is working in the Screen Shot.

[image: XP Google Chrome]

.

Remember that there are major limits in what you can do with XP